# Non refreshable Jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm working on a header wich has included a JSP page (notification menu). The problem is that I lose my 'notifications' when I refresh any page (the menu is included in the header) or access any other module. Is there a way to make it static so it only loads once and never changes during an user session?. I'm kinda noob into JSP/JAVA please be gentle :)

http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/jquery-notification-menu/ -> that's the menu i'm currently using

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: No, a browser refresh is a browser refresh. And if you remove my ability to refresh my window, I'm irritated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser can refresh whenever it wants. You should be saving the status of the notifications to a database, with a column that tells whether they have been viewed by the user or not and modify that column when the user explicitly dismisses the notification.